# Mutually exclusive Switches

Tags: forms, checkboxes, toggle

The software I am designing for has 3 functions, which can be turned on or off with Switches. However, due to how the software works, the following rules apply:

- At least one function must be enabled at all times.
- Switch (C) cannot be enabled together with (A) or (B).

---

The current implementation looks like the image below. 
If you enable (C) then (A) and (B) will be disabled automatically, and vice-versa.

[image]

I'm not very happy with this though. I wish I could make it clearer to the user that C is mutually exclusive to A and B.

Perhaps Switches are not viable? Perhaps I can add something before or after the switches that indicate their relation? Spacing? Grouping?

I'm out of ideas.

---

**Edit:**

[image]

We previously had the above design but abandoned it because we wanted to display contextual options in an expandable section below each option (i.e checking A would give you configuration options related to A. Same for B and C. The "tree" nesting/indentation would get too big, which is why we decided to lift all options to the top-level.

Comment: Please get rid of the switches.  It is hard to tell which is meant to be on or off.  It is always a guessing game.  Does left mean on or does right mean on?  They are a bad idea, and should never have been invented as GUI elements.

Comment: Ah, switches. Destroying usability since 2005. Back then, we had radios and checkboxes, which were clean, simple and obvious.

Comment: If all options are visible on a screen close together, the user will immediately see what happens after he clicks option C (A and B are automatically disabled). If there are configurations between the options this behavior will be a lot more opaque, since pressing one of the options will completely change the whole page-layout (configuration sections disappearing and appearing) which will make it very hard to process or reason about what exactly is happening.

Comment: @JRE I beg to disagree. Perhaps they are a bad fit for this particular problem but they have been used in both android and iOS for well over a decade and nearly everone has a smartphone. These are not new daring concepts anymore. They are standard. I also find it exceedingly hard to believe that anyone does not know which state above is on and which one is off.

Comment: I don't.  The colors are not standardized in any way.  Is left on or is left off?  Damifno.  I am posting from an Android phone.  It uses the stupid switches.  The only thing that makes them halfway useful is that something obvious usually changes when you change the state of the switch.  Manual switches (hardware, like light switches) have labels on both sides **and** something obviously changes when you flip the switch.

Comment: @JRE So you have a gray color and a light blue color but you cannot tell which one is meant to signal "off"? The illuminating side is obviously communicating "on". Even the switches in your car work that way.... In addition, I've never seen a switch where you flip it to the left to turn it on. I've only ever seen Left = off and Right = on.

Comment: To my way of thinking, when the switch nub is towards the text then that function would be active.  If the GUI switches had a marking (text label) on both sides, then it would be obvious.  The function in the description nearest the nub would activate.  GUI switches are ambiguous, though.  Only one side is labelled.  You all seem to think "nub away from the description is on," but that's the opposite of the way real switches work.

Comment: What is the default background color?  Blue or gray? You think it is obvious, but it isn't.  For all I know, gray is the on color.

Comment: @JRE I'll agree with you that they are misused a lot. But that does not mean they are bad. Here's how I would use a switch with text only on one side (unrelated to OP): *Allow us to collect of anonymous usage data* [Switch]. Or even: *Airplane mode* [Switch]. I think these are clear anyway.

Comment: Check box and done.  Much clearer.

Comment: @JRE for all I know a square with a tick symbol in it means "off".

Comment: Relevant: Material Design's guidelines on checkbox and switch usage.
https://material.io/components/checkboxes#usage
https://material.io/components/switches#usage
Essentially, switches are better for isolated, immediately-applied changes (like a light switch activating a light).

Comment: @JRE Checkboxes semantically only mean a selection of something and are almost always accompanied by a save button or some other control input. They should rarely be used on their own. Same thing with radio buttons.

Comment: @TheRubberDuck Exactly. Checkbox here is not better than Switches, despite what people might say in the comments. This is a well researched topic by the largest UX teams in the world and applied to tens of billions of devices. Like, there is no debate to be had really.

Comment: @Chris I'm not really here for the debate, which probably has its own UX.SE question(s) anyway. It's probably too vague to say with generic labels like "Option A". I could see it either way, personally.

Comment: @TheRubberDuck I know. I was commenting generally.

Comment: @Chris I'm confused, you seem to be implying that your switches have immediate action, no save buttons, etc.? But then it also seems like there's a whole page for this, with multiple sub-configurations below A, B, C....wouldn't that typically have a Save button?

Comment: Also, I'm confused about the complaint that it was too big. The nested version seems to be adding one line vertically and one tab of indentation horizontally...which isn't really a huge increase in size. Is this meant for some mobile application where screen size is expected to be very small?

Comment: @user3067860 No, all inputs have immediate action. The application is mainly desktop, but 2/3 of the screen is occupied by a large video player. The player must be displayed along with the configuration options as these directly affect the video. So in a way, yes, space is somewhat limited.

Comment: @Chris I believe you when you say you've "never seen a switch where you flip it to the left to turn it on." This is the reason why it is often good to make decisions about what makes sense in a UI by consulting others with more experience in that area. (In the meantime, consider referencing an [Android phone menu in Arabic](https://i.imgur.com/5BTebba.png) for a digital example, and [this circuit breaker panel](https://images.tmbi.com/wp-content/uploads/wwwroot/tfh/projects/apr17_reset_breaker_1.jpg) for a real-world example.)

Comment: @user91655 we have a colorblind mode for this exact problem. No solution is perfect.

Comment: @cjs Some languages are read from right to left, so of course the control is reverted there too. We're talking about general UX solutions and not localization-specific issues. Surely you understand that I am generalizing. The experience of many here is really up in the air for me when they are trying to argue that Switches are the worst without knowing exactly how they are used in this context. If they truly were so bad, how come Apple - probably the single most influential UX body in the world - still has them?

Comment: @cjs In addition, we have had usability tests with several dozen people. While that's not really that many, not a single person ever hesitated on how to use the switch. It feels to me that some (not everyone!) are only here to make an argument based on a controversial topic and to look smart, rather than making a strong argument for their opinion. Instead, people resort to ridiculous claims, like, they don't know if the blue means off or on. We've had these controls for **at least** a decade, and any other allegation is in my eyes just a troll - especially if you frequent these forums.

Comment: @cjs by the way, that circuit breaker panel is mounted sideways lol. Judging by the labels, on was meant to be "up" and off "down".

Comment: Regardless of how the breaker panel is installed, the direction which is `on` is different for each column.

Comment: @StvnW ah yes, indeed. Speaking of great UX :D

Comment: @Chris _"If they truly were so bad, how come Apple - probably the single most influential UX body in the world - still has them?"_ Becuase Apple's priority is to make things look cool, which often leads to compromises in UX design, as Bruce Tognazzini (you know Tog, right?) and others have been [explaining for more than a decade now](https://www.fastcompany.com/3053406/how-apple-is-giving-design-a-bad-name).

Comment: Note that this is not Apple taking a "wrong turn" at some point: Apple started making things more "minimal" at the cost of usability from the very start. Consider the single-button mouse: it has to cover the functions of at least two of the Altos mouse buttons, but unlike two or three buttons, has only one obvious affordance. So they had to hide additional functionality under the "double click" (something completely unknown to users at the time) and drop the useful context menu functionality.

Comment: @Chris And also, no, the ciruit breaker panel is not mounted sideways, it's mounted in the most common orientation for such panels (and there are good reasons to mount it in that direction). You're now just proving that you're willing to make pronouncements on things you know little about.

Comment: @cjs You brought in a circuit panel which has text and labels in three different orientations to make a case example of good UX. I have to turn my head sideways to read what the switches do, but hey "here is an example where a switch in the "left" position means "on". How many can relate to that brilliant UX compared to millions of UI's. You want to make a case example for the 1% to look smart? Go right ahead.

Comment: @cjs You're also making pronouncements about the research we've done. How many usability tests we've done. How many UX designers are involved in my team. What UX knowledge I have. Maybe I just came here to get a second opinion? As you can see from the different proposals posted here, there is no obvious solution.

Comment: @cjs I find checkboxes difficult to use. Switches can be bad **if used incorrectly**. As with everything. I'm done with this conversation. I already asked you to stop once. I'm gonna ask you politely again. Unless you have *an actual answer* to post down below, kindly refrain from commenting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your initial instinct to use radio buttons (and as suggested by @musefan) for the primary alternatives is the semantically correct choice. (Whether to use switches or checkboxes for the secondary options can then be left open to debate...)

There are ways to achieve the visual grouping other than indentation that will retain the full horizontal width to use for displaying more information or sub-options. Here is one possible suggestion:

[image]

Comment: This suggestion is, in my eyes, as good as you can get it. It's a nice balance between semantics and function. It could use some polish, but I think it's an excellent starting point. Thank you!

Answer (score 35):

The way I see this is that you have two exclusive groups of options, it just happens that the second group only contains one option.

Something as simple as the word 'or' will help a lot - that way it's unambiguous as to the grouping.

[image: Two exclusive groups of options]

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could use this approach but with all options stacked.

Comment: I see this as the nicest design but it is still missing something. It does not explain the user that either C or one of A,B must always be selected. ------ Also how it should behave when the user tries to change the switches to an unsupported combination? For example in the state as shown above: a) turning off A - should it be blocked (not obvious from the appearance) or should it turn on B or C? b) turning on C - should it turn off A and B (and forget their state)? ------ I think that flipping an on/off switch there and back in a well designed GUI should not change other settings.

Comment: Ah - that's interesting, @pabouk, I hadn't even considered that. You make an excellent point about how to handle turning off C. In that case, [musefan's approach](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/141271/30287) covers all the requirements.

Comment: @Chris - is it possible for you to tell us the true labels of these options? I think having the right context would open up other solutions that make more sense.

Answer (score 29):

Your constraints limit you to only four valid choices:

1. A and B
2. Only A
3. Only B
4. Only C

I would just use a set of 4 radio buttons.

Comment: I feel like this would be tricky for the user to parse if the labels were at all complex. Presumably they're not going to be called 'Option A, B, C' in the real system.

Comment: If a simple pairing of two options is too complex, each of the two options is probably too complex as well.

Comment: This approach is not bad but will become a problem in itself if the system gets a 4th option in the future.

Comment: Yes, but that is a problem for if a new option gets added. If you *expect* that to happen, then it would be better to prepare for it than to require an overhaul to the UI.

Comment: @chepner you never know with product owners ;-)

Comment: @Chris: So the solution also needs to work for potential future extensions? If that's a requirement for answers you should emphasize that in the question.

Comment: @Schmuddi There is no answer to that. The nature of software is such that unforeseen changes and additions can rarely be entirely excluded. Flexible designs are many times preferred for this very reason. In other words: I'm not to say what is to be expected in the future.

Comment: I like this solution because there's no ambiguity (as in "is this a bug or what happens with these switches that are disabled randomly?"): clearly, all the available options are actual options that are deliberately offered.

Comment: @chepner Most of other approaches will also require rework if a fourth option is added which can be combined with existing options.

Comment: @Chris This approach only becomes a problem if the system gets a 4th option _and_ you refuse to revise the design beyond adding another switch when it gets the 4th option. Why would someone already modifying the design deliberately make it worse when he could just as well make it better?

Comment: @cjs Revising designs are costly and it's if there is a solution out there that does not require a revision, wouldn't you agree that would be the best solution? Every solution has benefits and drawbacks. This design has many benefits but it also has this particular drawback. What I meant by a 4th option wasn't a 4th option in the set of radio buttons, but rather a 4th "letter". With the same rules (all combinations are valid, except C which can only be selected alone), you would now have 8 choices rather than 4. 8 radio buttons seems like too much to me.

Comment: @Chris Revising designs like this should not be costly; software developers have spent decades working to make changes like this cheap. If it's still expensive for a team to make simple changes like this they have a large problem that's going to be hurting every part of their UI, since there are always plenty of changes you _didn't_ anticipate.

Comment: @cjs cheap is relative

Answer (score 22):

What I understand from the question is that A, B, and C are independently selectable but selecting C disables A or B.

What is the way to graphically show three selectors where one is linked to the other two?

[image]

Or how to graphically show the link:

[image]

Comment: The latter design is nice and pretty clear I think. Though each option has contextual parameters that can be set. I think your design in combination with the latter suggestion from @musefan could work. Thanks!

Comment: Another variant I've seen of the second example is a background color highlight that moves behind whatever set of elements is active, with the inactive elements greying out. Bonus points for a rudimentary CSS animation.

Comment: Also please never use radio buttons as checkboxes.

Comment: I think this GUI would give me the opposite signal.  Radio-buttons usually imply mutual-exclusivity within a group, so grouping two radio-buttons together makes them look mutually-exclusive (rather than mutually-compatible).

Comment: If the first layout would be used, I'd probably expect the region around Option A and Option B to itself a radio-button, while Options A and B within it would each be a check-box.

Comment: This will just tell me that A and B are linked in some way (possibly both part of some logical group or category), but I would only figure out that it has anything to do with mutual exclusivity after switching the switches a few times (after I get past the initial confusion of having one switch disable another). Putting an "OR" between the two (i.e. combining this with the top-voted answer) would make what's going on here much clearer.

Comment: This seems to be more something that will make sense after a user's already figured it out ("oh, so that's why there's a block around those"), rather than something that clearly conveys a meaning, which isn't really ideal in UIs (unless you use the same thing in many other places).

Comment: This has the same problem as some of the other designs, where it's not clear what is supposed to happen if you have, say, C selected and then you try to turn off C. (Should both A and B turn on? Only A? Only B? You just can't turn off C?) I think radio buttons are the only design element we have that means "you must select at least one".

Answer (score 21):

**Option 1**

Note: this was the original answer before the question was updated (see comments).

I think what you essentially have here is two groups. You have the "A and/or B" group, and you have the "C" group.

Only one group can be selected (so use radio buttons). However, if you pick the first "A and/or B" group, then you have sub-options that allow you to select either A or B or both (use checkboxes).

So I would recommend a design similar to this:

[image]

Note that it is hard for me to give you a good example of what the text should say, as your example is very generic, but hopefully you understand my point and can apply some more sensible text based on your actual specification.

---

**Option 2**

After your comment that you require additional configuration options to appear depend on the selected options.

I would suggest that rather than trying to make the advanced options appear inline with the root options, separate it into a "2 step" process:

- Step 1: Select which options you want to enable
- Step 2: Configure each of the selected options

You could make this a 2-page wizard, or you could simply put it on the same screen/page but as individual sections.

Something like this. Where the configuration options panels dynamically appear based on which root options the user selects.

[image]

---

**Option 3**

You might consider having the configuration options as a modal form. This would allow you to keep the initial options screen much simpler. Depending on your validation requirements for the configuration options, this may not be the best approach. But if additional configuration is optional (i.e. defaults are provided for all config options already) then it could work well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: We actually had this exact design before but abandoned it because we wanted to display contextual options in an expandable section below each option (i.e checking A would give you configuration options related to A. Same for B and C. The "tree" nesting/indentation would get too big, which is why we decided to lift all options to the top-level. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @Chris I think this is important information that you should include in your question. The whole concept of "automatically disabled other options" only really works if the user can see all options on screen at once. If you have a risk other config options pushing the main options off the screen, it's not wise to use a toggle approach. I do have another idea though so I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update as well. Not a bad idea. What happens when the user selects C? The right-hand cards are replaced by the corresponding one for C?

Comment: @Chris. Yes, in that instance you would only see the config options for C. Likewise, if the select only A, then they see only config panel for A. In a "mobile" screen view, the panels can appear below the options panel, so that works too. I will also add a 3rd idea which may or may not be suitable depending on your logic for config options.

Comment: Another issue with this sort of design is that while it's clear that options A/B are not compatible with option C, it's not clear that at least one of A or B must be selected.

Answer (score 4):

Many of the custom home builder sites offer options on their plan viewers.  They tackle this swapping the slider control to a stop sign on the mutually exclusive item.  Any sub-items appear with the main slider selection.

**Nothing Selected:**

[image]

**Mutually exclusive item, with sub-item added:**

[image]

Comment: This doesn't address the requirement that B is independent from A (So you could select the Outdoor Kitchen without first selecting the Patio). It's a good approach for sub-options, though.

Comment: I was more trying to highlight the visual cues that some items were mutually exclusive.  There isn't really anything obvious that they are mutually exclusive until you start clicking around.  Toggling things on/off can be fun.  Not sure you *have* to spend a ton of time indicating things are mutually exclusive to the users when most likely they are going to just start toggling options to play around on the screen anyway.

Comment: Sometimes play/exploration is good, but I think it depends a lot on the context of the application. House designer, yes definitely.

Answer (score 3):

You can try a dropdown (or radio buttons) with clear choices:

```
Please choose your options:
- A
- B
- A and B
- C
```

You only have these four options when I understand your post correctly. So don't increase the user's mental load through unusual and complex UI, but provide a simple list, even when it has one item more than the other possible solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to make a new control, designed for this precise task, you could make it look and behave like this animation:

[image: composite control selecting (a) OR (b) OR (a AND b) OR (c)]

As you can see, it allows only the combinations you have requested, but it would require more programming than would an arrangement of premade controls. If A, B and C are longer than single letters, you could either add a key just below, or have it vertical rather than horizontal and put descriptions alongside.

You will have to think carefully about accessibility features for users with visual impairment: description, feedback on change of selection that would have to work with a standard screen-reader. Keyboard control should be easy, though: arrows!

Comment: Interesting design! Quite a daring concept, but pretty good nonetheless. Thanks